# How mutate array in GraphQL by Lokka?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo

My query: imageList - object;
I can not understand how to mutate by variable;

```
let query = `query _($type: NoteTypeEnum!, $imageList: ???){
    addNote(note: {
    imageList: [{  
       fileName: $fileName,
       url: $url,
       uuid: $uuid
    }]
    }) {}
}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

types of lists are defined with square brackets and within them the type of the list, so in your case I guess it should be:

```
let query = `query _($type: NoteTypeEnum!, $imageList: [Json]){
addNote(note: {
imageList: [{  
   fileName: $fileName,
   url: $url,
   uuid: $uuid
}]
}) {}
}`;
```